# Difference between new ArrayList<String>() and new ArrayList<>()

Tags: java

Please help me to understand what is the difference between two lines written below, I know both is valid but I want to know which one is better?

```
List<String> val = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and

```
List<String> val = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: question is different and title is different.

Comment: One doesn't work prior to the introduction of the [Diamond Operator](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-7/Diamond-Operator.htm) in Java 7...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Which one is better?

   Personally, I like using the first one as I think it is more clear to me, but it is your personal preference and others do think it is redundant.
2. What is the difference?

   There is no difference between the two lines, they mean the same thing in Java 7 (if you are targeting Java 6 use the first one).

[EDIT]:

Also, as Elliott Frisch notes (thanks for the helpful clarification) due to type erasure, there is no way to differentiate between the two code snippets as it removes the generics from both. This works up to JDK 5, when generic types were first introduced.

Comment: With type erasure they mean the same thing in every jdk back to 5.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch with type erasure wouldn't (unnecessary) type casts be inserted? I just want to make sure I understand my terminology, the type parameters are not unbounded?

Comment: I mean at run time, the contents of a Collection are Object(s).

Comment: Ah I (think I) see, at runtime there will be no way to differentiate because the generics are all removed from both?

Comment: That is precisely my meaning.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - With type erasure, how the second line (List<String> val = new ArrayList<>();) will be handled.

Comment: @ABP At run-time `List val = new ArrayList();`, hence the term type erasure.